# Getting undefined method 'call' when using inject on an array

Tags: ruby

I have an xpath in a string and to see what's being returned from nokogiri in each bit i'm trying to traverse the string and thus the path.

The xpath string I'm using is:

```
//div[contains(@id,"results")]//div[contains(@class,"page-nav")]//ul[contains(@class,"pagination-tabs")]
```

To do this, I'm splitting the string on the `//` and then using inject to get the doc into the loop block, I execute xpath, do a `puts` and then return the segment so I can do the next bit, like this:

```
get_mpc_tag[:path].split.('//').inject(doc) do |el,section|
  a = el.xpath("//%s" % section)
  puts a
  a
end
```

but I'm getting a wierd error (well, weird to me):

```
undefined method `call' for #<Array:0x007f9f8c032f68> (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 foo.(bar)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo.call(bar)
```

You are trying to call `call` on the result of `split`, which is an `Array` and doesn't have a `call` method.